# Magento - How to get the store country?

Tags: magento

how to get the store country, to show it in the transsactional E-mails?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by store country?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To achieve country object first you have to get country code for current store

```
$countryCode = Mage::getStoreConfig('general/country/default');
```

then get country Object

```
$country = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->loadByCode($countryCode);
```

When you have the object, there is no problem to assign it to variable in email template

```
$mailer = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer');
$mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
    'country' => $country
));
```