# Display default country field in a phtml file - magento

Tags: magento

Can anyone tell me how I display the Default country of the magento store in a phtml file?

:)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magento - How to get the store country?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791145/magento-how-to-get-the-store-country) Please make use of the search function, it really works! :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->getDefaultCountry() ?>
```